# Customize the listforms(newform.aspx) using sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form, list-form

I am working on customizing the newform.apx of the list called customerList.  So I went ahead and created a newform1.aspx using designer.  This newform1.aspx has all the columns of the customerList.  Then I set the newform1.aspx as default and created new item.

The values got saved in the list.  I moved fields around and arranged them and now whenever I add an item to the list through newform1.aspx, the values do not get stored in the list.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: its Sharepoint 2010

Comment: What kind of arrangements did you do with your columns? Did you try undoing the changes and saving? Do you get any errors while saving?